# Formula to provide lastest date for specified item

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two spreadsheets titled Amy and Data.

The spreadsheet named Amy has 2 columns - Response time and Time/Date Assigned. The Response Time column will always contain either 1, 5, or 24.

In Spreadsheet named Data, this is where I would like to have a formula that would provide the latest date that a 1 hour response time was assigned. In the example below, the formula would provide 5/31/14 as answer.

Below is what Spreadsheet Amy looks like:

```
           Column A       Column B
Row 1   Response Time   Date Assigned
Row 2        24           5/20/14
Row 3         1           5/20/14
Row 4         5           5/30/14
Row 5         1           5/31/14
Row 6        24            6/2/14
Row 7        24            6/3/14
Row 8         5            6/3/14
```

Thanks for any assistance that you can offer.  I am not even sure which function I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` and an array formula.

Use IF to return the date if the response time is 1:

```
IF(A2:A8=1,B2:B8)
```

and MAX to get the biggest date:

```
MAX(IF(A2:A8=1,B2:B8))
```

and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it look at the whole list, not just the first row

```
{=MAX(IF(A2:A8=1,B2:B8))}
```

Answer (score 0):

More suitable for a much more complex scenario, but you might want to consider a PivotTable. For example with Response Time for ROWS and Max of Date Assigned (suitably formatted) for Σ Values then you would be able at a glance to see not only the date for 1 hour but also all other maxima.